# How to use Array_agg without returning the same values in different Order?

Tags: sql, array-agg

When using Array_agg, it returns the same values in different orders. I tried using distinct in a few places and it didn't work. I tried using an order before and after the array and it would fail or not properly exclude results.

I am trying to find all fields in the field column that share the same time and same ID and put them into an array.

Columns are **Fieldname, ID, Time**

```
select b.Field, count(*)
from (select Time, ID, array_agg(fieldname) as Field  
  from a
  group by 1,2
  order by 3) b
group by b.field
order by 1 desc
```

This produces duplicate results
For example I will have:

```
Field Name    Count
Ghost,Mark    1234
Mark,Ghost    1234
```

I also tried this below where I add a subquery where I first order the fields alphabetically when grouping time and ID but it failed to execute. I think due to array_agg not being the root query?

```
select a.Field, count(*)
from
  (select Time, ID, array_agg(fieldname) as field
  from
    (select Time, ID, fieldname
    from a
    group by 1,2
    order by 3 desc) a
  group by 1,2 ) b
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: which database system are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Databricks